# flutter integration test command with driver

Tags: flutter, flutter-integration-test

Currently I use `flutter driver --target=integration_test/main.dart  --driver=test_driver/main_test.dart` to run flutter integration tests. I need `driver` file so that I can allow `permissions` before running app.  It is [advised to use](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140149#issuecomment-1857313732) `flutter test` for integration testing but couldn't find proper documentation on how to set argument for `driver` file.

Also, is it possible to run test with driver in firebase test runner?